# Changing IFrame font style/size/color

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the font style, color, and size of the text inside an IFrame. The text is stored locally in a .txt file. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M). Is the page that has the iframe (call it parent.html) and the page **inside** the iframe (call it child.html) both in the same folder/directory (same domain)?

Comment: So you are showing a text file in an Iframe?? And want to change the CSS of the text file?? If so then NO you cannot. However if you make your text file to be a html then you can. Or read the contents of the text file and place it inside  div (or inside an Iframe body) and you can change the CSS of it

Comment: if file stands on same server, you may want to use PhP include('text.tx'); inside a div with an id ...

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by following code:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="text.txt"></iframe>

<script>
var frame = document.getElementById('myFrame');
    frame.onload = function () {
        var body = frame.contentWindow.document.querySelector('body');
        body.style.color = 'red';
        body.style.fontSize = '20px';
        body.style.lineHeight = '20px';
    };
</script>
```

Comment: you sure that You can change the CSS of a `TEXT` file??

Comment: Yes, I have tried this code in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and it is work :) The conent of text file become content of body.

Comment: ok, hmmm interesting, So what happens if there is a script section in the text file?? will it execute?

Comment: As it is mentioned in the question file extension is `.txt`, so indise iframe it is just a plain text.

Comment: Nice answer, but the OP was asking for a .txt file

Answer (score 1):

To do this, the easiest method would be to directly include the styles in the file.

Just change your txt file to a .html file and use the style tag to change the look of the page via css

For example, your style tag could look like this:

```
<style>
body{
   font-family: sans-serif;
   color: red;
   font-size: 2em;
}
</style>
```

This will create rather large text with your default sans-serif font and a red text color